# Framebox - two rows

Tags: framed

Please how to set two rows in a `framebox`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech,english]{babel} 

\begin{document}
\framebox[\textwidth]{\centering \textbf{Instruction:}\\ Find the ground state energy of a helium atom in first-order perturbation theory.} \par
\end{document}
```

Is the instruction grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\framebox` creates a single line box. Click [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes) for more info.

Since you have many lines in your box, you could use `framed` environment, from [the package of the same name](https://ctan.org/pkg/framed).

Off-topic: don't use `\\` for going to a new line, just leave an empty line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}\centering\textbf{Instruction:}

Find the ground state energy of a helium atom in first-order perturbation theory.
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you and how to set bold border please? I editted the code in question.

Comment: @Johannes_B Elisabeth asked a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458298/mdframed-bold-frame. I deleted the edit to her question.

Comment: For a bold border, you have `\setlength{\FrameRule}{some length}`.

Comment: @Elisabeth you can have bold border also with `framed`: see Bernard's comment.